# JVM only uses 4 cores

Tags: ubuntu, java, cpu, multithreading, taskset

I have a processor-intensive Java program and I want it to use all 8 available cores on the machine.

I've run `taskset` and it reports the mask to be:

```
pid 5897's current affinity mask: ff
```

But in `top` (when running 12 (heavy) threads):

```
5897 ubuntu    20   0 9099664   1.7g  18608 S 400.7  11.1  25:52.83 java
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Is the program capable of using more than four threads?

Comment: yes, it runs 12 threads